# Blender not using full hardware capacity!

Tags: animation, gpu, hardware

I just completed my new computer setup to work extra fast!

Anyhow, while animating a simple cloth simulation with blender, it simulates quite slowly and my task manager is showing me that my gpu is working at the highest capacity, compared to the other hardware components, at only 20% !!

I am wondering why it is so unnecessarily slow and if anyone has an idea how to find the bottleneck?

heres some info:

cpu AMD Ryzen 9 3900X

gpu Nvidia RTX 3080

64GB RAM

Cheers,

Pradamarfa

Comment: Cloth sim system is quite old, it is probably not optimized like it could be.

Comment: Have you baked the simulation? Physics simulations such as cloth sim require mostly (single core) CPU power. Your GPU will be idle most of the time during the calculations

Comment: Also what means "simple"? How many vertices has your cloth sim? Do you use default settings? If the mesh is low-poly but you have 3 more levels of subsurface divisions or more than one subsurface division modifier then the cloth sim is no longer easy to calculate for your CPU. The same is true when the cloth quality value or collision values are very high in the settings...